# Zooming into a particular polygon

Tags: arcgis-server, polygon, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am getting the polygon id by doing

```
identifyParams.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;
identifyTask.execute(identifyParams, function(result) { 
     var i;
     var polyId= new Array();
     for(i=0; i<result.length;i++){              
       polyId[i]=result[i].feature.attributes["UNIQPOLYID"];
     }
```

I want to zoom in to the polygon when the value of i is 1. How will I zoom in to that particular polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the geometry of the feature, and then zoom to it's extent.

I would use a function like this:

```
function ZoomTofeature(feature){
//get the geometry of the feature
var shape=feature.geometry;
//check if geometry is polygon
    if(shape.type==='polygon'){
        //get extent
        var featureExtent=shape.getExtent();
        //now zoom to this extent
            map.setExtent(featureExtent);
    }else{
        //not a polygon
        alert("Shape is not a polygon");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may just zoom to the feature's geometry bounds. It also works for other type of features.

```
//Assume the polyFeature is the feature you want to zoom to.
var featureBounds = polyFeature.geometry.getBounds()
map.zoomToExtent(featureBounds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the `centerAndZoom` API, this method accepts an argument of type `mapPoint`. You can get the centroid of a polygon by chaining `getCenter()` after `getExtent()`

```js
var center = feature.geometry.getExtent().getCenter()
map.centerAndZoom(center).then(()=>{
  //do something
})
```

The API Reference gives an example in another method description, see  `toScreen(mapPoint)`
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html